# How can I fix this sqlite3.OperationalError / sql syntax error?

Tags: python, sqlite

My sqllite Database is not working and I have some errors which I assume to be about SQL syntax.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("SONGS.db")

conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE SONGS
         (ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
         Song-Name       TEXT     NOT NULL,
         Artist       TEXT    NOT NULL,
         Released       TEXT    NOT NULL,
         Views       TEXT    NOT NULL);""")
conn.close()

conn = sqlite3.connect("SONGS.db")

conn.execute("INSERT INTO SONGS (ID,Song-Name,Artist,Released,Views) \
      VALUES (1, 'Counting Stars', 'OneRepublic', 'May 31, 2013', '2,458,427,299' )");

conn.execute("INSERT INTO SONGS (ID,Song-Name,Artist,Released,Views) \
      VALUES (2, 'Waka Waka', 'Shakira', 'June 4, 2010', '2,052,927,789' )");

conn.execute("INSERT INTO SONGS (ID,Song-Name,Artist,Released,Views) \
      VALUES (3, 'I Want It That Way', 'Backstreet Boys', 'October 25, 2009', '515.894,015' )");

conn.execute("INSERT INTO SONGS (ID,Song-Name,Artist,Released,Views) \
      VALUES (4, 'Psycho', 'Post Malone', 'March 22, 2018', '400,195,600' )");

conn.execute("INSERT INTO SONGS (ID,Song-Name,Artist,Released,Views) \
      VALUES (5, 'Till I Collapse', 'Eminem', 'September 16, 2015', '335,842,184' )");

conn.execute("INSERT INTO SONGS (ID,Song-Name,Artist,Released,Views) \
      VALUES (6, 'These Days', 'Rudimental', 'January 25, 2018', '270,529,823' )");

conn.execute("INSERT INTO SONGS (ID,Song-Name,Artist,Released,Views) \
      VALUES (7, 'Juice WRLD', 'Black & White', 'October 3, 2018', '5,268,766' )");

conn.execute("INSERT INTO SONGS (ID,Song-Name,Artist,Released,Views) \
      VALUES (8, 'Shotgun', 'George Ezra', 'June 14, 2018', '18,291,200' )");


conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

There is my code and here is the **error**

> line 25, in 
>       Views       TEXT    NOT NULL);""") sqlite3.OperationalError: near "-": syntax error

Comment: Hi! Try formatting your code, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting It makes things a lot more readable and you're more likely to get help.

Comment: When seeking debugging help, your question should contain a [mcve]. This code is not a minimal example. A basic debugging technique is to simplify your program (by removing `conn.execute`, for example) util you have the smallest possible program that still gives you the same bug. This is often called "divide and conquer debugging", and helps you understand and fix bugs, and also makes it much easier for others to understand your code and spot what's wrong.

Comment: Also, you should include the full error traceback in the question. The traceback contains essential information for understanding an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

, This error is due to a field in the database table called `View`

I don't think you need `;` for `conn.execute` statements.

hence `error line 25, in Views TEXT NOT NULL`

Another recommendation, use String substitution:

```
insert = "INSERT INTO SONGS (ID,Song-Name,Artist,Released,Views) VALUES ({}, {}, {}, {}, {})"
```

And when you insert, do:

```
conn.execute(insert.format(1, 'Counting Stars', 'OneRepublic', 'May 31, 2013', '2,458,427,299'))
```

Comment: Thanks. Ill try this now. - My lesson is ending now so i will have to try it next Monday, thanks for the response!